# My answer duplicated itself

Tags: bug

I added an answer here: *[Can Picasso queue for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131941/can-picasso-queue-for-me/46278447)*

When I double-checked what I had written I decided to add a comment for clarification. When I saved the edit, it was saved as a second answer.

I don't know if it can be reproduced, but it does seem like a bug.

Comment: Maybe it's just an answer so nice, it posted itself twice?

Comment: @Bart the votes are doubled as well?

Comment: Interesting to note is the share/perma link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278419/984830) is identical for both. So your joke could well be prophetic @rene

Comment: MySQL, at a guess?

Comment: @NickCardoso You likely compared the last numbers in those links, which is your user id. They definitely have different answer ids though, I just checked.

Comment: Oops, @rob You're correct... i only checked the end